# Data displaying twice on webpage, but there isn't duplicates in database. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out why my data is displaying twice on my webpage, but there aren't two of the same entries in the database. Here is the code I am working with.

```
$truckDueList = "";

$sTruckDue = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT idTruck, truckNumber, status             
    FROM Truck             
    WHERE Truck.id_divisions = :idDivision
");
$sTruckDue->bindValue(":idDivision", $_SESSION['division']);
if ($sTruckDue->execute()) {
    while($rowTruck = $sTruckDue->fetch()){
        $dueList = "";
        $more = false;
        $workNeeded = false;

        $sTruckAlertType = $dbh->query(" 
            SELECT idTruckAlertType, description
            FROM TruckAlertType
        ");
        while($sTruckAlertType && $row = $sTruckAlertType->fetch()){

            $sTruckAlert = $dbh->prepare(" 
                SELECT truckAlerts.idTruck, truckAlerts.flag
                FROM `truckAlerts`, Truck
                WHERE Truck.status != 'inactive'
                    AND truckAlerts.idTruck = :idTruck
                    AND truckAlerts.idTruck = Truck.idTruck
                    AND truckAlerts.idTruckAlertType = :idTruckAlertType
                    AND truckAlerts.flag > 0
            ");
            $sTruckAlert->bindValue(":idTruck", $rowTruck['idTruck']);
            $sTruckAlert->bindValue(":idTruckAlertType", $row['idTruckAlertType']);
            $sTruckAlert->execute();
            $workNeedRow = $sTruckAlert->fetch();
            if(isset($workNeedRow['idTruck'])) {        
                    $workNeeded = true;
                    if ($more == true){ 
                        $dueList .= ", ";
                    }
                    $more = true;
                    $dueList .= "<span class='notice_level_" . $workNeedRow['flag'] . "'>" . $row['description'] . "</span>";
            }
            if($workNeeded == true){    
                $truckDueList .= "
                    <tr style='cursor:pointer;' onclick=\"DoNav('vehicleDetails.php?tid=" . $rowTruck['idTruck'] . "');\">
                        <td width='20%' class='rightSide'>" . $rowTruck['truckNumber'] . "</td>
                        <td class='rightSide leftSide'>" . $dueList . "</td>
                        <td width='15%' class='leftSide'>" . ucfirst($rowTruck['status']) . "</td>
                    </tr>
                ";
             } 
        }
        $sTruckAlertType->closeCursor();    
    }
    $sTruckDue->closeCursor();
}

if($truckDueList == ""){
    $truckDueList = "
        <tr>
            <td colspan='3'>No Vehicles Due</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

I can't post an image of whats being displayed but it looks something like this:

ID: Work Needed:

100 Oil Change

100 Oil change, Tire Rotation

For some reason it displays an extra oil change, but only does it with oil change. Doesn't duplicate tire rotations. I've checked and rechecked the database, there is NOT duplicate entries, but seems to be displaying as if there is. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the whole block:

```
if($workNeeded == true){    
            $truckDueList .= "
                <tr style='cursor:pointer;' onclick=\"DoNav('vehicleDetails.php?tid=" . $rowTruck['idTruck'] . "');\">
                    <td width='20%' class='rightSide'>" . $rowTruck['truckNumber'] . "</td>
                    <td class='rightSide leftSide'>" . $dueList . "</td>
                    <td width='15%' class='leftSide'>" . ucfirst($rowTruck['status']) . "</td>
                </tr>
            ";
}
```

right after `$sTruckAlertType->closeCursor();` — it definitely should be on the same level of nesting as resetting all the locals (`$dueList` etc.)

Currently you output this on every `$sTruckAlertType->fetch()`.